# Disable drag selection on react-big-calendar

Tags: reactjs, drag, react-big-calendar

I don't see anything in API for disabling this behavior.

I just want users to have to click on a specific date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the prop `onSelecting`. For example: `onSelecting = {slot => false}`

Comment: This worked for you? It still lets me select multiple events and prevents me from scrolling on mobile...

Comment: same here! It doesn't prevent me from dragging.

Comment: My approach is not the best. But it works like this: while mouse pressed down, user can still feel "they are selecting areas", but once they let go of the mouse, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had to get selection for clicked date, without drag.
Used the **onSelectSlot** with required logic.

```
onSelectSlot={(e) => {
  if (e.slots?.length > 1) return; // or a message
  alert("onSelectSlot" + JSON.stringify(e));
}}
```

Note: this wont handle drag selection styling!!